OpenCV with a FLIR Lepton
I Have a FLIR Lepton hooked up to a raspberry pi 5. I have been able to confirm the Lepton works, and run it by following the instructions from the GroupGets Github repo.
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow("preview")
cameraID = 0
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(cameraID)

if vc.isOpened(): # try to get the first frame
rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
rval = False

while rval:
cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
rval, frame = vc.read()
key = cv2.waitKey(20)
if key == 27: # exit on ESC
break

That is the code I have, taken from this flir tutorial:
https://www.flir.com/developer/lepton-integration/Project-People-finding-with-a-Lepton/
When I try to Run this code, I get the error that it can't open the camera from the index, I ran a script to check for all camera indexes, and there were none that showed up. But the FLIR Lepton is connected and can be run. SO how can I run OpenCV with the FLIR lepton then?

format your code. your indentation was lost. that is syntax, not cosmetic, in python. -- @wohlstad?

@ChristophRackwitz I agree indentation must be fixed. It slipped by me when I approved from the staging ground - my mistake.

Not sure what happend when I copy pasted, indentation is correct in the code editor on raspberry pi, and I double checked it now.

are you aware that you can [edit] your question? -- what resolutions does the camera support? if it doesn't support 640 by 480 (OpenCV default basically everywhere), that'll cause such an issue. create the VideoCapture with frame size given in the constructor through the params argument.
